# How to identify "irreducible factors" in a monoidal or cartesian category

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Is there "a categorical way" of speaking of objects in a monoidal category which can't be written as a tensor product? (We have to be careful with multiplication by the unit.)

The same can asked for a cartesian category and there might be a smoother way of answering the question. Both questions seem interesting to me.

Comment: Sure, $X$ can be called irreducible iff it is [irreducible](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/irreducible+element) in the monoid of isomorphism classes. Thus, $X$ is not invertible up to $\cong$, and whenever $X \cong A \otimes B$, then $A$ or $B$ are invertible up to $\cong$. Is this really just your question?